# Problema con niveles de usuario en PHP

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un login y el objetivo es que según el tipo de usuario vaya a una pagina determinada.

```
<?php
$_SESSION['nivel'] == 1;

if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page']){
    include 'phpfiles/'.$_GET['page'].'.php';
    if($_SESSION['nivel'] == 1){
        include 'phpfiles/cliente.php';
    } elseif($_SESSION['nivel'] == 2){
        include 'phpfiles/proveedor.php';
    }
} else {
    include 'phpfiles/home.php';
}
?>
```

No importa el nivel que asigne, siempre el sitio me muestra en el `home.php`. Quizás es una pavada, pero no lo puedo resolver.

Agradezco la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Si siempre entra en tu else es porque no se está cumpliendo la primera condición de tu if, es decir `isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page']` haz un var_dump de esa variable para ver si existe y con que llega a ese momento.

Comment: Puedes colocar la petición GET que envías

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias cosas:

1. Esto no es una asignación, que es lo que supongo pretendes: `$_SESSION['nivel'] == 1;` Ahí no asignas `1` a la clave `nivel` de la variable de sesión. Ten en cuenta que el doble signo de igual es para comparaciones.
2. Vamos a escribir un código más limpio, recogiendo variables, usando ternarios y haciendo un solo include en cada bloque. Así tienes un código más limpio y más fácil de testear.
3. En la parte del `elseif` hay una especie de limbo. ¿Qué ocurre si la variable de sesión no tiene nivel, o si el nivel no es ni `1` ni `2`. El estilo de código que he usado permite ver con más claridad ese limbo y resolverlo de alguna manera.

Esta es la propuesta. Si tienes alguna duda dilo en comentarios.

```
<?php
  $_SESSION['nivel'] = 1;
  $mPrefix='phpfiles/';
  $page=!empty($_GET['page']) ?  $_GET['page'].'php' : NULL;
  if($page){
      include "$mPrefix$page";
      /*
        Puede que haya un "limbo" aquí en tu lógica ...
        Asumo que, si el nivel de la sesion es 2 incluye a proveedor 
        y de lo contrario inclue a cliente ... 
        Pero, ¿qué pasa en otros casos posibles: 
        nivel 3, nivel N, ningún nivel?
        He ahí el "limbo" al que me refiero 
      */
      $mSession = ($_SESSION['nivel'] == 2) ? "proveedor.php" : "cliente.php";
      include "$mPrefix$mSession";
  } else {
      include $mPrefix."home.php";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Cedano, entiendo y ni había preste atención en esto `$_SESSION['nivel'] == 1;`, pero trate de resolverlo con tu ejemplo. Por otro lado, si, hay 5 niveles de usuarios y 8 subniveles, y eso es lo que tengo que resolver en estos días. Te agradezco nuevamente la ayuda!

Comment: @Sebastian para cuestiones complejas puedes valerte de 1 estructura más simple, como un array por ejemplo, así evitas complicados bloques `if` o `switch ... case`, pudiendo buscar en el array por su clave la URL a redireccionar, por ejemplo: `$mUrls=array (1=>'home.php', 2=>'compras.php', 3=>'ventas.php', 4=>'login.php', 5=>'otro.php');` luego, en base al valor que estaría en la variable de sesión o donde sea, obtendrías a qué página debe redirigir, por ejemplo: `$url=!empty($mUrls[$_SESSION['nivel']]) ? $mUrls[$_SESSION['nivel']] : 'default.php';`  Tendrás en `$url` la URL asociada o default